# Create an html element from string with js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an html elemnt from string in js.

The string is: `"<p class='text-muted'> come and see how good I look </p>".`

In the past I did this with php by echo it out and now I build the client side only with angularJS and I have no clue how to do it.

I tried to bind the string to the page but, as expected, it prints the whole string without encode the string to html elemnt..

I tried to look for an answer in the internet and specificly in this community without succuess..

Does it possible, and if so, How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want it in JavaScript or Angular? Show some context on how you are using it since there are multiple ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-bind-html` directive to bind a string of html to an element. The string should be sanitised first for example by injecting `$sce`and calling `$sce.trustAsHtml()` on the string to bind.

Example controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.template = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p class="text-muted"> come and see how good I look </p>');
});
```

And in html

```
<div ng-bind-html="template"></div>
```

[Here's a quick example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rf851hjJAQBQyA9caSUo?p=preview)
You can type in html and click to bind it

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a String definition of html to any DOM Elment using the property 'innerHTML'.

```
yourDomEl.innerHTML = '<div class="your-class"><a>Link</a></div>';
```